# JAVA comparing just Times (getTime function)

Tags: java, compare, gettime

I have REPORTDATE field where I want to take the value just of the hours and minutes.
`reportdate.getTime()` returns this for example: 1439967368798

I want to compare if TIME from reportdate (hours and minutes) are between:

```
if reportdate>=06:45 and reportdate<13:45 then a=1;
if reportdate>=13:45 and reportdate<20:45 then a=2;
if reportdate>=20:45 and reportdate<06:45 then a=3;
```

I did not succeed to find some instructions on web.
Should I try with this by using the value that I am getting from getTime (1439967368798) or with some other method?

Comment: You should probably use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for this.

Comment: Either use JodaTime or Java 8's Time API, for example `LocalTime lt = new Date(1439967368798L).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();`, this will then allow you to use `before` and `after` (and `equals`) to compare other instances of `LocalTime`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `reportDate` is an instance of `Date`. The `getTime()` function returns the underlying long of the Date, thats why you see this long number - miliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

What you need to do is convert the date to a calendar and then use the get() Method with the appropriate field constant.

This information is for Java 7 without any libraries. It would be wise to use a library like JodaTime or the Java8 Time API.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/ComparingCalendars.htm) is an example how to do that.

Comment: Hi I cannot use JodaTime because I am programming this in some IBM application with limited Java framework where I cannot include some additional libraries

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
if (date.after(format.parse("06:45")) && date.before(format.parse("13:45"))) {
 a=1;
}
```

Comment: yes will it work also when comparing 20:45 and 06;45?

Comment: where are you comparing with value from REPORTDATE field?

Comment: @Dejan Sorry, I show principle, not a ready solution. Report date could be inserted here Date date = reportDate;

Comment: @Dejan "comparing 20:45 and 06;45". You meant, does this works `format.parse("20:45").after(format.parse("06:45"))`? Yes.